# Elements always save in index 0 of an array of objects (C#)

Tags: c#

Making my 2nd ever non-console application in C# (pretty new to programming as a whole). The user saves recipes and a list of ingredients for the recipes. The recipes are saved in an array of "Recipe" objects (recipeList) but any recipe i try to save is saved in recipeList[0]. I feel like there's an easy solution to this but I've kinda stared myself blind and just fail to identify the issue. I've yet to write code to validate inputs and such.

Class for managing recipes

```
internal class RecipeManager
    {
        private Recipe[] recipeList = new Recipe[200];
        private int numOfElements = 0;
        public RecipeManager()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
            {
                recipeList[i] = new Recipe();
                recipeList[i].Name = string.Empty; ;
            }
        }
        public int Index(string value)//finds an index
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                if (recipeList[i].Name == value)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
        public void NewRecipe(Recipe recipe)//saves new recipe in empty index
        {
            recipeList[numOfElements] = recipe;
            numOfElements +=1;
        }
        public string GetRecipe(string value)//returns desired recipe
        {
            return recipeList[Index(value)].Description;
        }
        public string Test()
        {
            return recipeList[0].Name;
        }
    }
```

Mainform

```
public partial class Mainform : Form
    {
        static Recipe currRecipe=new Recipe();
        FormIngredients formIngredients = new FormIngredients(currRecipe);
        RecipeManager recipeManager= new RecipeManager();
        const int maxNumOfIngredients = 50;
        const int maxNumOfElements = 200;
        public Mainform()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeGUI();
        }
        public void InitializeGUI()
        {
            btnAddRecipe.Enabled = false;
            btnClear.Enabled = false;
            btnDelete.Enabled = false;
            btnEditBegin.Enabled = false;
            btnEditFin.Enabled = false;
        }
        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnAddRecipe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currRecipe = formIngredients.Recipe;
            recipeManager.NewRecipe(currRecipe);
            lBoxRecipes.Items.Add(currRecipe.Name+" "+currRecipe.Category+" "+currRecipe.NumOfIngredients());
            formIngredients.Recipe.ClearIngredients();
            btnClear.Enabled = true;
            btnDelete.Enabled = true;
            btnEditBegin.Enabled = true;
            rTxtRecipe.Clear();
            txtName.Clear();
            cBoxCategory.SelectedIndex = -1;
            //rTxtRecipe.Text = recipeManager.Test();
        }

        private void btnAddIngredients_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            formIngredients.ShowDialog();
            currRecipe.Name=txtName.Text;
            currRecipe.Description=rTxtRecipe.Text;
            currRecipe.SetCategory(cBoxCategory.Text);
            btnAddRecipe.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void lBoxRecipes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name=lBoxRecipes.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0,lBoxRecipes.SelectedItem.ToString().IndexOf(" "));
            rTxtRecipe.Text=recipeManager.GetRecipe(name);
        }
```

Form where you manage ingredients

```
public partial class FormIngredients : Form
    {
        Recipe recipe=new Recipe();
        public Recipe Recipe { get { return recipe; } }
        public FormIngredients(Recipe currRecipe)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btnDeleteIngredient.Enabled = false;
            btnOk.Enabled = false;
            recipe= currRecipe;
        }
        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recipe.newIngredient(txtIngredient.Text);
            lBoxIngredients.Items.Add(txtIngredient.Text);
            txtIngredient.Clear();
            btnDeleteIngredient.Enabled = true;
            btnOk.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void txtIngredient_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void btnDeleteIngredient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recipe.RemoveIngredient(lBoxIngredients.SelectedItem.ToString());
            lBoxIngredients.Items.Remove(lBoxIngredients.SelectedItem);
        }

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lBoxIngredients.Items.Clear();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Recipe class

```
public class Recipe
    {
        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        private string description;
        public string Description
        {
            get { return description; }
            set { description = value; }
        }
        private string[] ingredients;
        private FoodCategory category;
        public FoodCategory Category
        {
            get { return category; }
        }
        public Recipe()
        {
            ingredients= new string[50];
            for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                ingredients[i]= string.Empty;
            }
        }
        public void SetCategory(string category)//converts and sets category for recipe
        {
            this.category = (FoodCategory)Enum.Parse(typeof(FoodCategory), category);
        }
        public void newIngredient(string ingredient)//adds ingredient to recipe
        {
            ingredients[EmptyIngredient()]= ingredient;
        }
        public int EmptyIngredient()//finds first empty slot in ingredients array
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                if (ingredients[i] == string.Empty)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
        public void RemoveIngredient(string ingredient)//removes ingredient
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                if (ingredients[i] == ingredient)
                    ingredients[i] = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        public string NumOfIngredients()//returns number of ingredients in recipe
        {
            int num = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                if (ingredients[i] == string.Empty)
                    break;
                num++;
            }
            return num.ToString();
        }
        public void ClearIngredients()//clears all ingredients
        {
            for(int i=0;i<int.Parse(NumOfIngredients())+1;i++ )
            {
                ingredients[i]= string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

FoodCategory is an Enum if not obvious.

So yeah any recipe i try to save in the array is saved to the first position even though numOfElements value is being properly incremented every time a recipe is added. I'm pretty sure i'm just overlooking something here but I've given it a couple of days and I can't not overlook it i guess. Also first time i post on this site if something's off.

Comment: General recommendation: use a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0) instead of an array. A list will grow and shrink as needed. You can remove items from a list and don't need to set them to string.empty or null. Just this change will makes the code 50% better to read. You'll find your problem easier.

Comment: The code is pretty confusing overall, but I have a sneaking suspicion that you're only ever editing/using *one* `Recipe` instance and are just populating your array with multiple references to that same instance.  When you debug, is it *really* "saving in index 0" or are all changes being reflected in every index where it's been saved?

Comment: `static Recipe currRecipe=new Recipe();` should probably not be `static` and you should eventually assign a `new Recipe()` at some other point in your code.

Comment: In addition to @ThomasWeller answer: use the count method of a list instead of predefined sizes in your for loops, or just convert them to foreach loops. you are building logic that is unnecessary if you just use the add and remove methods from lists. 

Also you have a RecipeManager class but you do a lot of logic in your Recipe class. I would suggest to just make a Recipe class with the properties it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Make recipeList a property and instantiate the property inside the constructor

```
public List<Recipe> RecipeList { get; set; }
public RecipeManager()
{
    RecipeList = new List<Recipe>();
}
```

so that you can use `RecipeList.Add(currRecipe)` instead of `recipeList.AddRecipe(currRecipe)` to add a new recipe to the list.

This means that you wont have to do any incrementing to add more recipes.